# Internal Error & Unauthorized Operation when creating a Managed Property in SP 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search, enterprise-search, managed-property

When trying to create a new Managed Property I get the following error:

[image: When I try to create a new managed property I am getting the following error]

My farm is just used for Search, so I have 2 servers, each having the Search components installed, Central Admin and Distributed Cache.

The SP logs files reports:

> SearchServiceApplication::CreateManagedProperty--Exception:
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an
>   unauthorized operation.     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchObjectAccessChecker.CheckParentFarmRights(IInternalSearchServiceApplication
>   app, SearchObjectLevel level, SearchObjectRight right, Boolean
>   throwException)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Schema.SecurityCheck(SearchObjectRight
>   right)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ManagedPropertyCollection.CreateWithPid(String
>   name, ManagedDataType managedType, Int32 pid)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ManagedPropertyCollection.Create(String
>   name, ManagedDataType managedType)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SchemaOperations... 8824ee9d-e134-40f2-01f9-574c85e1a49b
>
> 05/03/2017 16:58:46.02*   w3wp.exe (0x23CC)
>     0x2998  SharePoint Server Search        Administration
>     afnqn   High        ....CreateManagedProperty(String managedPropertyName,
>   ManagedDataType type, SearchObjectOwner owner)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.CreateManagedProperty(String
>   managedPropertyName, ManagedDataType type, SearchObjectOwner
>   owner)    8824ee9d-e134-40f2-01f9-574c85e1a49b

Comment: Off the top of my head...Did you launch the session from the Central Admin icon (elevated)? Are you a Farm Admin? Do you have Shell Access?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem with my account which is a domain admin and solved by

- Adding the account to the Local Administrator's Group!